# Follow up: drawing-sequence-logos-in-d3 using images

Tags: d3.js

Follow up of this question: [Drawing sequence logos in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341800/drawing-sequence-logos-in-d3/)

It was a really nice example (thanks for your time).

I was trying to modificate using images instead of letters(as cmonkey suggested), but no luck so far 'cause of the height resize. (it doesn't stretch the height as I wished).

Any insights would be super-welcomed.

```
column
    .selectAll("images")
    .data( function(d) { return d.bits; })
    .enter().append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(e){ 
        if (e.letter == "A"){return "a.png"}
        if (e.letter == "T"){return "t.png"}
        if (e.letter == "G"){return "g.png"}
        if (e.letter == "C"){return "c.png"}
        ;})
    .attr("y", function(e) { return y(e.y0); })
    .attr("x", function(e) { return x(e.position); })
    .attr( "height", function(e) { return ( y(e.y0) - y(e.y1) ) ; } )
    .attr( "width", function(e) { return ( x.rangeBand() ) ; } );
```

Any insights ?

Comment: Have you considered using the `transform` attribute to get the desired dimensions?

Comment: would it be possible to transform height ? I really don't know how it would work using transform (I am super new on web-languages)

Comment: You can stretch the coordinate system, see [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the image with the original height of the letter png, and then use the transformation `translate` to move it into place, and `scale` to stretch it.

A good explanation can be found [here](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Transforming_the_Coordinate_System).

Here's a very basic example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yb2kr/

```
var svg = d3.selectAll("body").append("svg")
        .attr("height",600)
        .attr("width",600)

svg.append("svg:image")
   .attr("xlink:href", "https://encrypted.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif")
   .attr("width", 200)
   .attr("height", 100)

svg.append("svg:image")
   .attr("xlink:href", "https://encrypted.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif")
   .attr("width", 200)
   .attr("height", 100)
   .attr("transform", "translate(0,100) scale(1,2)")
```

I'm not sure that images is a better solution .. depending on how much they're stretched, they might become distorted. Fonts, on the other hand, should hold their sharpness.